# Passing arguments to shell script in AWS SSM not working

Tags: shell, hdfs, aws-ssm

I am trying to run a Shell script using boto3 SSM on an EC2 insctance. Please find below the code snapshot -

```
def run_shell_command(command):
  region = 'ap-southeast-1'
  ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm', region_name = region)
  commands = [command]
  resp = ssm_client.send_command(
    DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript",
    Parameters={'commands': commands},
    InstanceIds=[instance_ids],
  )

  logging.info('Below is the output')
  time.sleep(5)
  command_id = resp['Command']['CommandId']
  output = ssm_client.get_command_invocation(
    CommandId=command_id,
    InstanceId=instance_ids,
  )
  logging.info(output)

def _drop_raw_tables():
  command = f"sh /c/b/a/script.sh args"
  logging.info(command)
  run_shell_command(command)
```

this code is working fine for shell scripts that don't take any **arguments** however I am getting below issue when running it with arguments- `hdfs: command not found /c/b/a/script.sh`
not sure why its taking it to hdfs?

Comment: You need to provide more information, such as an example of args with which the problem occurs. Does your script work properly if you execute them manually, without SSM?

Comment: I have a similar issue, did you find a solution? @ZabielskiGabriel https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73839404/how-so-send-arguments-to-ssm-using-the-js-sdk

Comment: @Chris sorry, I don't have any exp in JS... But I assume that you should wrap message into a 'parameters' structure - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_SendCommand.html

Comment: @ZabielskiGabriel I hear you but I don't understand what that would me. 
I tried this: `Parameters: { Message: [ 'message' ] } ` and it return an error. 
I have also opened an discussion on the repo https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/discussions/3984

Comment: @Chris what error you recieved?

Comment: @ZabielskiGabriel this error message {"message": "Internal server error"}

Comment: And nothing more?